# Почему не срабатывает 2 условие?

Tags: javascript

```js
let img = [img4, img1, img2, img3];
let next = document.querySelector('.next');
next.onclick = () => {
  if (div.src = img[0]) {
    img[0].src = img[1].src;
    console.log(div);
  } else if (div.src = img[1]) {
    img[0].src = img[2].src;
    console.log('a');
  };
};
```

```
   //Почему при клике первое условие срабатывает и пустой src img становится 
    // = img[1].src,потом по логике это условие должно быть false?становится 
    // false,и должно выполниться 2 условие т.к первое условие false?
   //Если я где-то не прав,не судите строго,нужно сделать галерею и 2 кнопки  
   //(next,prev);При клике на next должна выводиться след. картинка из 
   //массива при клике на prev предыдущая картинка из массива
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну тут условие кривое, = это присвоение, а == или === это уже проверка на соответствие, плюс ко всему перед else if не ставится точка с запятой, поскольку это неотемлимая часть конструкции if

Comment: @user355360  нет тебе прощения смертный бугагагашечка :)